# Flow player and supported file formats

Tags: video, flowplayer

Flow player claims that it supports all file formats.
Do the video files need to be converted to flv format to support the above statement ?
Or can we play video in their original format(avi,mov)?

I am using free version with "flowplayer-3.2.8.min.js" and "flowplayer-3.2.9.swf" to render view on web pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flowplayer supports FLV, H.264 and MP4 Video formats. Basically all the video formats supported by Adobe Flash; they are listed [here](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/technical-facts.html#formats).

You have to convert the files to one of those above formats.

Hope this helps.